# Javascript propertyIsEnumerable returns false but still enumerable

Tags: javascript

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable):

> The propertyIsEnumerable() method returns a Boolean indicating whether the specified property is enumerable

But when I run the following code, it outputs:

> method info is NOT enumerable
>   but can be seen in for loop

```
var Person = function(name){
  this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype.info = function(){
  console.log("Name =", this.name);
};

var me = new Person('Mike');
console.log('method info is' + (me.propertyIsEnumerable('info') ? '' : ' NOT') + ' enumerable');
for(var k in me) {
  if (k == 'info') {
    console.error('but can be seen in for loop')
  }
}
```

This  confuses me.

---

UPDATE

As answered by @RobG, since `propertyIsEnumerable` only checks property on object itself, what should I do if I want to iterate over properties only on the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*propertyIsEnumerable*](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.7) only checks properties on the object itself, it doesn't consider the prototype chain. So:

```
me.propertyIsEnumerable('info')
```

returns false because there is no *info* property on *me*, it's on *Person.prototype*. It shows up in the *for* loop because it will iterate over all properties of *me*, including those inherited from its constructor's prototype.

Because of this behaviour, *propertyIsEnumerable* was used as a substitute for *hasOwnProperty* in early versions of Safari where *hasOwnProperty* was either buggy or not present (I can't remember which).

Comment: Thanks @RobG . But what should I do if want to iterate over properties only on the object?

Comment: You can use a for loop with *hasOwnProperty* check and ignore those that fail, or you can iterate over the members of `Ojbect.keys(me)` (see [*ECMA-262 ed5 §15.2.3.14*](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.14)), which is required to return an array of own enumerable properties in the same order as a for loop (but that might be different in different browsers so I'm not sure why the specification requires that). There's a polyfill for older browsers on [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).